# How can I compare two strings to see if one is greater than the other

Tags: swift, if-statement, string-comparison

I am working on a basic card game. I have the user shuffle two cards and I want to be able to know if the cards are equal or if one is greater than the other or less than the other. Currently I can only tell if they are equal.

```
   //Randomize Dealer Card
func randomDealerNumber(){

    let randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(8)
    if randomNumber == 0 {

        dealerNum.text = "10"
    } else if randomNumber == 1 {

        dealerNum.text = "1"
    } else if randomNumber == 2 {

        dealerNum.text = "2"
    } else if randomNumber == 3 {

        dealerNum.text = "3"
    } else if randomNumber == 4 {

        dealerNum.text = "4"
    }else if randomNumber == 5 {

        dealerNum.text = "5"
    } else if randomNumber == 6 {

        dealerNum.text = "6"
    } else if randomNumber == 7 {

        dealerNum.text = "7"
    }
}



let playerCard = playerNum.text
let dealerCard = dealerNum.text
if playerCard == dealerCard {
    print("These two strings are considered equal")
}
```

Comment: You can compare strings.  What exactly are in your strings and what does "greater than" mean?

Comment: lets say the first label says 7 and the second one says 3. I want to be able to click a button that then says label 1 is greater then label 2.

Comment: Are they always numbers, or can they be "A", "K", "Q", "J" as well?

Comment: it will always numbers

Comment: And how did the numbers get into those labels?  Did you have some internal ints in your program that you assigned to the labels with something like: `label1.text = String(card1)`?

Comment: yes its not the best system right now but if you tap a button it randomizes 1-10 and which ever it lands on it makes that label that number

Comment: It is possible to convert the string back to an Int, but it is easier to just keep track of the Int you generated in the first place.  Keep the ints in a property of your viewController, and then just compare the ints.

Comment: im a little confused on how I would go about that?

Comment: Edit your question to share more of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't store values in your `UIControl`s.  The values should be in variables that represent your model and then just compare the values in your model.

I would suggest keeping the random values you generate as `Int` and then just compare them.  Adding property observers (`didSet`) to those will allow you to set the labels when those value are set:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var dealerNum: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var playerNum: UILabel!

    var dealerCard = 0 {
        didSet {
            dealerNum.text = String(dealerCard)
        }
    }

    var playerCard = 0 {
        didSet {
            playerNum.text = String(playerCard)
        }
    }

    func randomDealerNumber() {
        var randomNumber = Int.random(in: 0...7)
        if randomNumber == 0 {
            randomNumber = 10
        }
        dealerCard = randomNumber
    }

    func compare() {
        if playerCard == dealerCard {
            print("same")
        } else if playerCard < dealerCard {
            print("less than")
        } else {
            print("greater than")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel like I must be missing something. This seems to exactly what I need but I can't seem to make it work. Its only showing less than no matter what that numbers change too

Comment: Debug.  Set breakpoints and look at values, or add print statements to print the values before the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is some oversight here, but if I am understanding correctly then your solution is quite simple. Another if statement:

```
if playerCard > dealerCard{
    print("Player wins!")
}
```

PPShein is correct. If you are talking about strings you should be using `count`.

Comment: Thats what I was assuming it was but I get this error "Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type 'UIContentSizeCategory'"

Comment: Did you attempt PPShein's solution?
if playerCard.count > dealerCard.count{
    print("Player wins!")
}

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to compare the integer values of the text fields. So you need to convert them to integer. (e.g. "10" to 10)

You can do like this

```
if(Int(playerCard) > Int(dealerCard)){......}
```

Just make sure you add sufficient safety checks to verify if the entered value can be converted to integer or not.

Comment: This won’t compile.